# Allowing eval in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron, two.js

I would like to write a small Electron application using Two.js but I realized Electron doesn't like anyone to use `eval`.

If I do this in `renderer.js`:

```
let u = eval('1 + 1');
```

I get this issue:

> Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed
> source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".

Of course I enabled `allowRunningInsecureContent: true` in the `webPreferences`.

Is there any way of running packages that use `eval` in Electron?

Comment: I don't have a direct answer, but do they allow use of the `Function` constructor? Have you tried that instead? ...`let u = new Function('return 1 + 1')();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add this to the `<head>` of your loaded html

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">
```

The issue comes not from electron but I assume you're running the electron application via a local web server, in that case you also need to provide the right configuration for the [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

Comment: Having same issue and specifying self won't work as I am importing a main.js script in index.html